# Parse FindInBackground: variable set in callback is null in main thread, but callback is also run on main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, parse-platform

I am doing Android app with Parse. I use findInBackground for query which does networking on background thread and callback in main thread (Parse documentation). Here what I try:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", clickedUserId);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    clickedUser = objects.get(0);
                    Log.d("yerchik/user","clicked user in thread: "+clickedUser);
                }
            });
```

So my logs for ("yerchik/user"):

```
D/yerchik/user﹕ clicked user in thread: com.parse.ParseUser@427229f0
```

So which means that I have my clickedUser variable set.

But If i try to access clickedUser object outside of my findInBackground call I get null. I though that "done" method runs on main thread, isn't it?

Comment: How are you trying to get the var from outside the done method ?

Comment: @RamiJemli, isn't that done method is run on main thread?

Comment: What @RamiJemli is getting at is that it's not about *where* you access the var but *when*.  More than likely, you're interrogating that value before the callback has been invoked.  This can be easily verified with a log statement.  If a "checking the var now" log happens before your "clicked user..." log, then you have your answer.

Comment: Yes, but i'm sure you're trying to get the results before the thread's done. Tell me how are you trying to access clickedUser object outside of findInBackground ?

Comment: @RamiJemli, yes, my logs show that I try to access clickedUser before callback is finished. What would you suggest to do?

Comment: @RamiJemli, so "done" method is run on background thread? Did I understand it correct? What if I will put all my code including the one where I access clickedUser into done method. And in here I have also findInBackground call.

Comment: Exactly danh. @yerassyl Don't get the value, let the Done method update the ui when it's called. For example, call a method declared in your activity inside the done ; updateUser(clickedUser), or use an eventbus library.

Comment: No, the done is in the mainthread. your problem is that you get data before the findInBackground is finished.

Comment: @RamiJemli, ok, I think I got it. So finally I put my code into done. Is it ok if I have another findInBackground inside done?

Comment: @yerassyl I don't recommend it. Use a good architecture to deal with calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Activity

```
public class Activity {

public void updateUI(ParseUser user){
Log.d("yerchik/user","clicked user in thread: "+user.getName());
textview.setText(user.name);
progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

Inside your controller

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", clickedUserId);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    activity.updateUI(objects.get(0));

                }
            });
```

This way the done method will update the ui when it's called(When the thread is finished).
 Hope this helps.